# Python decorator to add class-level variables

Tags: python, inheritance, metaprogramming, decorator, python-decorators

I have 2 classes A and B:

```
class A(object):
    x = 0

class B(object):
    y = 0
```

How can I make it so **B** "inherits" **A**'s class-level variables (**x** in this case) by using decorators? Is it at all possible? The desired behavior (if possible), after decorated, **B** would look like this:

```
class B(object):
    x = 0
    y = 0
```

---

Note: If anyone wants/needs to know why I'm asking this, it's simply to make SQLAlchemy's Concrete Table Inheritance look nicer in code, although I can see many use cases for such behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can; you can use a class decorator that takes class A as an argument, then updates the decorated class for you:

```
import types

class copyattributes(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source

    def __call__(self, target):
        for attr, value in self.source.__dict__.items():
            if attr.startswith('__'):
                continue
            if isinstance(value, (property, types.FunctionType)):
                continue
            setattr(target, attr, value)
        return target
```

The decorator copies anything that is really an attribute (not a function or a property), and doesn't start with a double underscore.

Usage:

```
class A(object):
    x = 0

@copyattributes(A)
class B(object):
    y = 0
```

Tested on the prompt:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     x = 0
...
>>> @copyattributes(A)
... class B(object):
...     y = 0
... 
>>> B.y
0
>>> B.x
0
>>> dir(B)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'x', 'y']
```

Comment: Just what I needed, and a quick answer too!